# more than one table with th having duplicated ids

Tags: xhtml, accessibility

I was wondering if I could have more than one tables like below. If you notice, I have applied th with the id="id", and id="name". so If have the more than one tables then, there will be many ths with the same id.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th id="id"></th><th id="name"></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td headers="id">1</td><td headers="name">First Name</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the use of the headers="id" above is not for styling purpose but for accessibility. in this case, I have only one simple table. 

prefixing the id with the table would not be so useful for users.

Comment: http://www.webaim.org/techniques/tables/data.php#headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't. An id must be unique in the document.

The simplest option is to apply a prefix to each id in a given table e.g. `id="mytable_name"`